# Using ADO.NET's Entity Framework with visual studio 2010 and NuGet - what's really happening

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ado.net, nuget

I'll need to use `ADO.NET EF` for my next project so I started a tutorial but ended up with installing `Entity Framework` while my Project was open through `Project -> Manage NuGet Packages` and then decided to walk through the tutorial using another project so I closed the current one and on the next day I created new `Console Project` for the needs of this tutorial. However when I tried to add `using System.Data.Entity;` to my `Program.cs` it didn't recognize the `Entity` so I had to install again `Entity Framework` from `NuGet` which seems kind of strange to me.

Is this how it should be - installing the `Entity Framework` for every project that will use it or I can install it once and then add it as reference where needed or something like that like many other packages in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't need to install Entity Framework for each project. Did you try adding a reference to the missing DLL? To do this, right-click your project in Solution Explorer and select Add Reference from the menu. You should be able to select System.Data.Entity from the .NET tab:
[image: Add reference dialog]